# Installing package ez on mac error

Tags: r, macos, install.packages

Just installed R and RStudio on macbook pro running Yosemite. When I try to install the `ez` package, I get a number of error messages, whether I use the R package manager or the `install.packages` command.

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
>     there is no package called 'quantreg'
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ez'

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you show what code you used to install the package?

Comment: try install.packages('quantreg')

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using the package installer and installing quantreg from there. Apparently install.packages had trouble doing that.

Comment: I cannot install the ez package on osx sierra, any ideas?